# Long Division with Boxes

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

I need to make a division worksheet for a specific student with ADHD. He often gets confused with the placement of the digits so this worksheet has to have boxes aligned in a very precise way. There are no available printed worksheets out there that have what I need. I've tried out a code for long division with boxes on my own, but it does not give me the desired image. I need to create an image similar to the one below with horizontal lines and minus signs.

[image]

I tried so far:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\divspace{\,}
\[ \arraycolsep=0em
\begin{array}{r@{\divspace}c@{\divspace}lllll}
       &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{15} &  \\ \cline{2-6}
    15 & \big) & \multicolumn{4}{l}{225}          &  \\
       &       & \fbox{1} \fbox{5}      &   &  &  &  \\ \cline{3-4}
       &       & \fbox{7}\fbox{5}       &   &  &  \\
       &       & \fbox{7}\fbox{5}       &   &  &  \\ \cline{3-5}
       &       &                        & 0 &  &  \\
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems like a got job for a `matrix`. What have you tried so far?

Comment: \documentclass[11pt]{article}
     \begin{document}
     \newcommand\divspace{\,}
     \[
     \arraycolsep=0em
     \begin{array}{r@{\divspace}c@{\divspace}lllll}
      & & \multicolumn{1}{r}{15}&\       \cline{2-6}
     15&\big)&\multicolumn{4}{l}{225}&\  & &                   \fbox{1} \fbox{5}&&&&\\cline{3-4}
  & &                   \fbox{7}\fbox{5}&&&\  & &                   \fbox{7}\fbox{5}&&&\\cline{3-5}
  & &                     &0&&
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}

Comment: At the bottom of your question is an “Edit” button. You can add this code to your question. A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Depending on how fancy you'd like the output, the `xlop` package seems to be designed for that kind of things.

Comment: You may also be interested in http://dpcarlisle.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/mathml-long-division.html  especially the link at the end that generates mathjax compatible latex markup for long division

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}

\newsavebox\wbox
\savebox\wbox{\kern2pt{\color{white}\rule{.5cm}{.5cm}}\kern2pt}

\begin{document}

\colorbox[rgb]{0,0,.3}{\parbox{5cm}{%
\baselineskip0pt
\lineskip4pt
\def\n#1{\b\raisebox{3pt}{\llap{\large#1\kern7pt}}}
\def\b{\usebox\wbox}
\def\,{\kern4pt}
\def\_{\mbox{}\kern4pt\kern.5cm}
\def\r#1{\par\kern3pt\mbox{}\_\kern1pt{%
   \color{white}\smash{\vrule height1pt width 1pt depth \dimexpr 1cm+7pt\relax}%
                \vrule height1pt depth0pt width\dimexpr .5cm*#1+4pt*#1+4pt\relax}\par\kern1pt}
\_\,\b\b\b\b\,\b\\
\r4
\n5\,\n3\n3\n8\n8\\
\_\,\b\\
\_\,\b\b\\
\_\,\b\b\\
\_\,\_\b\b\\
\_\,\_\b\b\\
\_\,\_\_\b\b\\
\_\,\_\_\b\b\\
\_\,\_\_\_\b
}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 10):

A semi-automatic TikZ solution.

The styles are set according to the keys `divisor length` and `dividend length`.
Though the actual input is still provided by the user.

It is important that cells that should get the assigned style has to have an text (which can be a space, e.g. `\␣` or `~`).

The same holds true for the additional row and column separation. The last end-row command `\\` for the TikZ matrix should not be input. The `longdivision` environment does this automatically.

### Interface

The line can be modified by:

```
\ldset{every line/.tyle={<style options for the line>}}
% or
\ldset{every line/.append style={<options to add to the existing line>}}
```

The line can be removed by `\ldset{every line/.style={}}`.

All boxes can be modified by the using the keys `boxes`. The style of the different kinds of boxes can be set by the keys `divisors`, `dividends`, `results`, `rests` and `others`.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc}
\newcommand*{\ldset}[1]{\pgfkeys{/ld/.cd,#1}}
\ldset{
    every long division/.style={
        fill=teal,
        column sep=.5em,
        row sep=.5em,
    },
    every box/.style={
        shape=rectangle,
        draw=none,
        fill=white,
        text width=1.3em,
        align=center,
        text height=0.95em,
        text depth=0.35em,
        rounded corners,
        execute at begin node=,%
        execute at end node=,
        name=\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn%
    },
    every divisor/.style={
        /ld/every box,
        fill=red!50,
    },
    every dividend/.style={
        /ld/every box,
        fill=yellow!30,
    },
    every result/.style={
        /ld/every box,
        fill=gray!20,
    },
    every rest/.style={
        /ld/every box,
        fill=teal!20,
    },
    every other/.style={
        /ld/every box,
    },
    boxes/.style={/ld/every box/.append style={#1}},
    divisors/.style={/ld/every divisor/.append style={#1}},
    dividends/.style={/ld/every dividend/.append style={#1}},
    results/.style={/ld/every result/.append style={#1}},
    rests/.style={/ld/every rest/.append style={#1}},
    others/.style={/ld/every other/.append style={#1}},
    divisor length/.code={%
        \def\qrrLDdivisorLength{#1}%
        \def\qrrLDrestLength{#1}%
    },
    dividend length/.code={%
        \def\qrrLDdividendLength{#1}%
        \def\qrrLDresultLength{#1}%
    },
    result length/.estore in=\qrrLDresultLength,
    rest length/.estore in=\qrrLDrestLength,
    every line/.style={
        draw=black,
        rounded corners=2pt,
        thick,
        line cap=round,
    }
}
\tikzset{
    execute style/.style={#1},
    invisible text/.style={text opacity=0},
}
\newenvironment{longdivision}[2][]{%
    \ldset{#2}%
    \def\QrrLDdivisorStyle{}%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\qrrLDdivisorLength}{%
        \xdef\QrrLDdivisorStyle{\QrrLDdivisorStyle, row 2 column \i/.style={every node/.style={/ld/every divisor}}}%
    }%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\QrrLDfirstRestColumn{\qrrLDdivisorLength+\qrrLDresultLength+1}%
    \edef\QrrLDrestStyle{}%
        \foreach \i in {\QrrLDfirstRestColumn,...,\numexpr\QrrLDfirstRestColumn+\qrrLDrestLength\relax}{%
            \xdef\QrrLDrestStyle{\QrrLDrestStyle, row 1 column \i/.style={every node/.style={/ld/every rest}}}%
        }%
    \tikzpicture[#1]
        \matrix[
            name=m,
            /ld/every long division,
            every node/.style={/ld/every other},
            row 1/.style={every node/.style={/ld/every result}},
            row 2/.style={every node/.style={/ld/every dividend}},
            execute style/.expand once={\QrrLDdivisorStyle},
            execute style/.expand once={\QrrLDrestStyle},
            matrix of nodes,
        ] \bgroup
}{
        \pgfmatrixendrow\egroup;
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\QrrLDbeforeFirstRestColumn{\QrrLDfirstRestColumn-1}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro\QrrLDafterLastDivisorColumn{\qrrLDdivisorLength+1}
        \path[/ld/every line] ($(m-1-\QrrLDfirstRestColumn.south west)!.5!(m-2-\QrrLDbeforeFirstRestColumn.north east)$) -|
                              ($(m-2-\qrrLDdivisorLength.south east)!  .5!(m-3-\QrrLDafterLastDivisorColumn.north west)$);
    \endtikzpicture%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{longdivision}{
    divisor length=1,
    dividend length=4,
    others={invisible text},
    results={invisible text},
    rests={invisible text},
}
   &[1em] 0 & 6 & 7 & 7 &[1em] 3\\[1em]
 5 &      3 & 3 & 8 & 8 & \\
   &      0 \\
   &      3 & 3 \\
   &      3 & 0 \\
   &        & 3 & 8 \\
   &        & 3 & 5 \\
   &        &   & 3 & 8 \\
   &        &   & 3 & 5 \\
   &        &   &   & 3
\end{longdivision}

\begin{longdivision}{
    divisor length=1,
    dividend length=4,
}
   &[1em] 0 & 6 & 7 & 7 &[1em] 3\\[1em]
 5 &      3 & 3 & 8 & 8 & \\
   &      0 \\
   &      3 & 3 \\
   &      3 & 0 \\
   &        & 3 & 8 \\
   &        & 3 & 5 \\
   &        &   & 3 & 8 \\
   &        &   & 3 & 5 \\
   &        &   &   & 3
\end{longdivision}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]